# Lambda capture lifetime/scope

Tags: c++, lambda

Consider the following code snipped (the question **is not** Qt specific):

```cpp
namespace gpds {
    class container
}

class my_widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY_MOVE(my_widget)

public:
    my_widget() = default;
    virtual ~my_widget() override = default;

    [[nodiscard]] gpds::container to_container(const std::filesystem::path& base_path) const;
};

struct tool
{
    std::string name = "Unnamed Tool";
    std::shared_ptr<QWidget> widget;
    std::function<gpds::container()> to_container;
    std::function<void(const gpds::container& c)> from_container;

    tool() = default;
    tool(const tool& other) = delete;
    tool(tool&& other) = default;
    virtual ~tool() = default;
};

void foo()
{
    // Create widget
    QWidget* widget = ...;

    // Create tool
    auto tool = std::make_shared<tool>();
    tool->widget = widget;
    tool->to_container = [&widget, this]() -> gpds::container {
        std::filesystem::path project_dir = ...;
        auto w = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<my_widget>(widget);
        if (not w)
            return { };
        return w->to_container(dir);
    };

    // Do something else with the tool
    ...
}
```

My question (sorry for the lack of the proper technical term): Is capturing `widget` in the lambda safe? I am experiencing issues where `my_widget::to_container()` does get called, but `this` is null - therefore resulting in a segmentation fault.
So interestingly within the lambda, both `widget` and the properly cast `w` are not null, yet within `my_widget::to_container()` `this` is null.

I do believe that this has something to do with either the life-time/scope of the lambda capture of `widget` but I fail to understand what to look for and how to achieve what I'm after properly.

Additional information:

- I am using C++17
- I made sure that the `my_widget` instance does not get destroyed before/during the call to `tool::to_container()`.

Comment: Using `this` isn't valid in a non-member function.

Comment: Don't capture objects with automatic storage by reference.

Comment: Why not `virtual gpds::container to_container() = 0`?

Comment: Because `tool::to_container()` is a generic interface but this specific instantiation with `my_widget()` requires an additional parameter (fs path). The lambda only serves the purpose of doing that.

Comment: At a closer look, it seems like what you really need to capture is a reference to `tool->widget`. (BTW: it's not clear at all what `this` is from that context, or why you need to capture it.)

Comment: Yep, capturing `this` is not needed. I edited the question to fix that. @molbdnilo please feel free to create an answer based on your comment - that was indeed the issue / the thing I missed.